# Window.location.replace doesn't work in Elementor

Tags: html, wordpress, elementor

Working on an emergency exit button for a domestic violence site. The exit button needs to take users to another site while also disabling the browser's back button in the process.

I'm working on this website in Elementor Pro and have put the below code in the custom attributes section of this button.

```js
$("#Exit").on("click", function(){
   window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=cute+cat", "newtab");   
   window.location.replace("http://google.com"); 
});
```

The button loads the suggested site but the window.location.replace doesn't disable the back button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After load of your page you need to disabled browser history:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);        
        window.onpopstate = function() {
            window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
        };
});
```